# SPFx Custon Property Pane not opening

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-custom-property-pane

I have created one custom `SPFx webpart` in which I have placed one link (My Links). By clicking on that link, I am getting links from SharePoint list. When user clicks on the link, it opens `Property Pane` (on the right side of window) in which I am showing important links.

Since last 1-2 days, webpart suddenly stopped working as it stopped opening `property pane` on the click of the link. It was working perfectly for last few months.

I was opening the `property pane` using below code

```
this.context.propertyPane.open();
this.context.propertyPane.refresh();
```

It is not calling (going through) default function of property pane mentioned below

```
protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration{}

protected onPropertyPaneConfigurationStart(): void{}
```

Comment: what version of SPFx are you using ? Are you using React in your project ?

Comment: We are using No-Code solution for our webpart development. We are using version 1.7.1